# Summing "Other" remaining after Top 5

Tags: oracle, group-by, aggregate, union

I have the query below which returns the top 5 sum per brokerage

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (SELECT b.brokerage_name AS Brokerage, 
              SUM(c.cost)      AS Cost 
       FROM   (tblquotesnew q 
               left join tblbrokeragesnew b 
                      ON q.brokerage_id = b.id) 
              left join tblcommissionnew c 
                     ON q.quoteid = c.quote_id 
       WHERE  c.calc_date >= Trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw') 
              AND c.calc_date <= Trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw') + 7 - 1 / 86400 
       GROUP  BY b.brokerage_name 
       HAVING SUM(c.cost) IS NOT NULL 
       ORDER  BY SUM(c.cost) DESC) 
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 5 
ORDER  BY ROWNUM;
```

Is it possible, in the same query, to have a sixth row returned for Other, which would be a sum of the remaining c.cost?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CTE ([`WITH` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2077142)), that precomputes all the `SUM(Costs)` and then `UNION ALL` two queries: one with the "top 5" from the CTE; the other one with the `SUM` of the rest:

```
WITH q2 AS
(
SELECT
    q1.*, row_number() over (order by Cost DESC) AS r
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        q.brokerage_id, SUM(c.cost) AS Cost
    FROM   
        tblquotesnew q 
        join tblcommissionnew c  ON q.quoteid = c.quote_id 
    WHERE  
        c.calc_date >= Trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')  AND c.calc_date <= Trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw') + 7 - 1 / 86400 
    GROUP BY 
        q.brokerage_id 
    HAVING 
        SUM(c.cost) IS NOT NULL
    ) q1
ORDER BY 
    Cost DESC
)
-- The "top 5"
SELECT 
    q2.r AS rank, b.brokerage_name AS Brokerage, q2.Cost
FROM 
    q2 LEFT JOIN tblbrokeragesnew b ON b.id = q2.brokerage_id
WHERE
    r <= 5
UNION ALL
-- The sum() of the rest (notice there is no group by; we add them all)
SELECT
    6 AS rank, 'Others', SUM(Cost)
FROM
    q2
WHERE
    r > 5 
ORDER BY
    rank ;
```

You'll get a result that looks like:

```
RANK | BROKERAGE   | COST
---: | :---------- | ---:
   1 | Brokerage 1 | 8351
   2 | Brokerage 5 | 2231
   3 | Brokerage 4 | 2227
   4 | Brokerage 3 | 2223
   5 | Brokerage 7 | 2210
   6 | Others      | 4420
```

---

NOTES:

1. Your `LEFT JOIN` on `tblcommissionnew` is actually an `INNER JOIN`, since you use tblcommissionnew in your where in such a way that it will eliminate all nulls.
2. You don't need to `JOIN` with the `tblbrokeragesnew` table until the end. Oracle probably is good enough to optimize it, but it's cleaner to do it explicitly. (I've assumed that `tblbrokeragesnew.id` is a PK).

You can check everything (including the table definitions I've assumed) at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=32072b246c69b5d76565ceab9bf27146)*

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same. 
My example uses hr.EMPLOYEES demo table:

```
select case when rn <= 5 then to_char(department_id) else 'Others' end dept,
       sum(ss) total 
  from (
         select department_id, sum(salary) ss,
                row_number() over ( order by  sum(salary) desc ) rn 
           from employees
          group by department_id
          order by ss desc
       )
 group by 
  case when rn <= 5 then to_char(department_id) else 'Others' end 
 order by max(ss) desc;
```